# How to clone trunk from branch in Subversion?

Tags: svn

We made the mistake of making a premature release, where we kept on having to update our branch to fix bugs.

Since these fixes weren't being committed to trunk, we need a way to merge these fixes into trunk.

I'm curious which solution is better for the situation.

```
(1) svn copy /path/to/branch /path/to/trunk
(2) svn merge --reintegrate /path/to/branch
```

The thing is, we want trunk to be an exact REPLICA of branch, so the copy solution might be more straightforward. I'm just not sure if this is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `svn copy` is appropriate when you create a branch out from a trunk. Recommended is `svn merge` while merging the changes(differences between the two sources) done in the branch to the trunk. `svn copy` wouldn't have been bad if you had an empty trunk.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to copy contents of a branch into trunk. You will probably have to delete trunk in one revision and copy branch in next one. Some SVN clients might be confused by that.

`svn merge` will work even if you started further development on trunk. I would go with that, as this might be your only option the next time.